# FileZilla works but sftp doesn't, how so?

Tags: sftp, filezilla

My webhost allows me to create FTP accounts, and I successfully used them with FileZilla to store backup files from my computer on those remote FTP accounts.

Now I am trying to upgrade from the FileZilla way of doing things to the more easily automatizable line-command way.

So, I do something like this in my terminal :

```
sftp -P 21 myftpusername@myurl.net
```

(I know the port is 21 because my webhost told me so).
But to my surprise, the terminal gets stuck with this command and outputs nothing (as of now it has been stuck for 10 minutes, so I'm not holding my breath for it to eventually work out).

Usually, I experience the opposite : the pure terminal way of doing things is more efficient than the nice-UI way, because the nice-UI is nothing but a wrapper around the command-line.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: sftp and ftp are two completely different protocols.  If your webhost supports only ftp, you can't use sftp to connect.   Try `ftp myurl.net`.  (And if your webhost really supports only non-encrypted ftp transfers, get a new webhost).  See http://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp

Comment: @user4556274 ftp myurl.net works. I'll ask my webhost if he supports encrypted ftp transfers or not.

Comment: sftp and ftps are too very distint protocols.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP is on the port 22 by default and you can connect to that using

```
sftp -P 22 myftpusername@myurl.net
```

But you talk about FTP. To the FTP service you can connect (obviously) using `ftp` tool:

```
ftp myftpusername@myurl.net
```